# Escape 'insert' mode in Amazon AWS Lightsail SSH Terminal vim

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, vim

Using Lightsail, running Ubuntu 16
Using the native web browser terminal ssh
Open a file in vim
Switch to 'insert' mode in vim
Make changes

Documented vim key sequences of escaping don't work.
I've tried:

Control [
Escape Key
Control C
Caps Lock

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the instance needed rebooted. Normal escape sequences now work.